# How to resize QTableWidget columns

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I have a *MainWindow* with a *QToolbar*, *QWidget* and a *QTabWidget*. The layout is "Grid". However, my window is resizeable and since I have a layout it works well. But there is one problem, in my *QTabWidget* I have a *QTableWidget* with two columns (layout is also "Grid"). If I resize my whole window, the *QTableWidget* resizes but not the columns.

For example, whenever I resize my window, my *QTabWidget* resizes and the *QTableWidget* in it too. Only the columns in my *QTableWidget* won't.

How can I resize them if my *QTableWidget* resizes?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Change the `ResizeMode` of the `QHeaderView`. For example, use:

---

```
horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode( 0, QHeaderView::Stretch );
```

to make the first column resize so the `QTableWidget` is always full.

---

2. Override the `resizeEvent` and set the widths of each column yourself when the `QTableWidget` has been resized.

Comment: In which function do I set the horizontalheader?

Comment: "Tables can be given both horizontal and vertical headers. The simplest way to create the headers is to supply a list of strings to the setHorizontalHeaderLabels() and setVerticalHeaderLabels() functions."
See [QTableWidget details](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#details) for this

Comment: in QT5: horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode( 0, QHeaderView::Stretch );

Comment: No in Qt5, it's horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::Stretch); The setResizeMode() method does not exist.

Answer (score 11):

1. To stretch last column:

   ```
   ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
   ```
2. To stretch column *#n*:

   ```
   ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(n, QHeaderView::Stretch);
   ```

Answer (score 6):

The best solution for this, in Qt5 you have to use `setSectionResizeMode` instead of `setResizeMode`

```
tabv = QTableView()
tabv.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch)
```

Also you can specify the `Stretch` mode when resizing

```
tabv.horizontalHeader().resizeSections(QHeaderView::Stretch)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ui->mytable->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to resize just the last column:

```
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the "resize mode" of your columns or rows with the QHeaderView and the method QHeaderView::setResizeMode().

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#setResizeMode

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#verticalHeader

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#horizontalHeader

Answer (score 1):

In Qt5 you have to use `setSectionResizeMode` instead of `setResizeMode`

```
QTableWidget* myTable = new QTableWidet;
QHeaderView* header = myTable->horizontalHeader();
header->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
```